# DocumentDB: Issue with updating list with multiple columns

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a document where I want turn of is_approved = false, if multiple columns are similar(posted_by and location).

I am not able to write a query which can get multiple duplicate columns..

```
function Prop() {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
    var response = getContext().getResponse();
    var counter = 0;
    var responseBody = {
        updated: 0,
        continuation: true,
        error: "",
        log: ""
    };

    // Validate input.
    getFullListOfPosts();

    // Recursively queries for a document by id w/ support for continuation tokens.
    // Calls findDuplicates(document) as soon as the query returns a document.
    function getFullListOfPosts(continuation) {
        var query = {
            query: "select * from root r ORDER BY r.created.epoch DESC"
        };

        var requestOptions = {
            continuation: continuation
        };

        var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, query, requestOptions, proccessFullListOfPosts);

        // If we hit execution bounds - throw an exception.
        if (!isAccepted) {
            responseBody.log += "Query not accepted";
            response.setBody(responseBody);
        }
    }

    function proccessFullListOfPosts(err, documents, responseOptions) {
        if (err) {
            responseBody.error = err;
            throw err;
        }

        if (documents.length > 0) {
            // If documents are found, update them.
            responseBody.log += "Found documents: " + documents.length;
            findDuplicates(documents);
        }
    }
    // Updates the supplied document according to the update object passed in to the sproc.
    function findDuplicates(documents) {
        if (documents.length > 0) {
            responseBody.log += "Updating documents " + documents.length;
            //for (var i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
                var first = documents[0];
                //The below query is not right. I want the above query to fetch all records with same posted_by and location and turn its is_approved to false
                var query = 'select * from root r WHERE r.is_approved = true AND  r.posted_by =  "' + first.posted_by + '"'; 
                var requestOptions = {
                    etag: first._etag
                };
                var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, query, requestOptions, identifyRecordsToDisable);

                // Update the document.                     // If we hit execution bounds - throw an exception.
                if (!isAccepted) {
                    responseBody.log += "Update not accepted";
                    response.setBody(responseBody);
                } 
        } else {
            getFullListOfPosts();
        }
    }

    function identifyRecordsToDisable(err, documents, responseOptions) {
        if (err) {
            responseBody.error = err;
            throw err;
        }

        if (documents.length > 0) {
            // If documents are found, update them.

            responseBody.log += "Found documents: " + documents.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) { 
                var j = documents[i];
                j.is_approved = false;
                responseBody.log += "^Updated" + j.id + j.is_approved + ""
                var requestOptions = {
                    etag: j._etag
                };
                var isAccepted = collection.replaceDocument(j._self, j, requestOptions, onReplaced);

                responseBody.log += "*" + j.id + j.is_approved + "*"
            }
            findDuplicates(documents);
        }
    }

    function onReplaced(err, updatedDocument, responseOptions) {
        if (err) {
            responseBody.error = err;
            //throw err;
        }
        counter++;
        response.setBody("Updated " + counter + " documents");
    }
}
```

In the above code, in the function 'findDuplicates', I am unable to write a correct query through which I can get all the duplicate records.
I tried using distinct, group by. having. I think documented doesn't support them

Comment: If you have more details, *edit your question* - don't post extra details in comments.

Comment: Can you provide example documents? Also, your first sentence is hard to understand. Can you reword/correct?

Answer (score 0):

The following query should help you find documents that match both property values.

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM root r 
  WHERE r.is_approved = true 
  AND r.posted_by =  "' + first.posted_by + '" 
  AND r.location = "' + first.location + '"
```